# Mac OSX: Keep window on top

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks

Does anyone know a way to keep window on top in OSX? I've tried  Afloat and works with about 15% of the apps out there. I know that you can snap windows to different corners but I often need to be able to keep one window (IM for instance) atop of another. I can't believe there isn't "pin window" functionality in OSX, natively or third-party.
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of afloat did you use? It seems that if you first install SIMBL 0.9.9 and then AFloat it should work well in Mavericks. There is no native way to do this and as far as I know AFloat is the only software enabling this tweak.

Comment: Thanks Josef! I've tried the latest Afloat, or rather the one that was modified to work on Mavericks. Sadly, it only covers a small number of apps; most IM apps are not covered, and neither are Office apps.
That's too bad that no one came up with a way to do it, I guess I'll keep looking..

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines, ever since pre-OS X, MacOS 8 and even pre-System 6 and 7 (see the [Original HIG PDF](http://interface.free.fr/Archives/Apple_HIGuidelines.pdf)).  Even modal dialogs were/are frowned upon. Hence, the difficulty.

The same question has been asked on SE Ask Different - see [Any nice, stable ways to keep a window 'Always on top' on the Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219116/any-nice-stable-ways-to-keep-a-window-always-on-top-on-the-mac)

Answer (score 1):

There is a successor to Afloat called [Fenêtre](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fen%C3%AAtre/id1286743037)

Also have you considered a tiling window manager such as [Amethyst](http://ianyh.com/amethyst/)?

This dynamically resizes windows so they are always visible and take up a certain portion of the screen.

Comment: This doesn't keep the window on top, with the same dimensions as the user originally required, when/if the window was resized, due to the tiling effect - or does it?

Comment: I posted this as an alternative because then there is no more need to worry about which window is on top of any other. They are all visible, they just dynamically resize.